# Azure Synapse Analytics monitor rowgroup skipping

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse

For reference i'm using a CCI table (Hash)
I'm looking for a solution to monitor if, for a query with a WHERE predicate on my Hash, Synapse is well skipping the invalid rowgroups.

Answer (score 1):

For a Hash-distributed table Synapse will eliminate Distributions, not rowgroups.  It's the partition scheme and CCI order that control row group skipping.  And that should be evident in the [execution plan](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/unlock-query-performance-with-sql-data-warehouse-using-graphical-execution-plans/).

For a CCI, each table has multiple (60) Distributions.  Each Distribution has one or more Partitions.  Each Partition has one or more Row Groups.  Each Row Group has up to 1 million rows.

For Heaps and Clustered Index tables it's the same, except each Partition has one Heap or Clustered Index.

Comment: OK. So if i'm right for a CCI non-orderer apart of skipping distributions, my query in my example didn't skip partitions inside the distribution  ?

Comment: I don't understand that question.  Perhaps if you added some details about your table and query to your question it would help.

Comment: Sure. I have a large (about 321 billions of rows) non-order CCI table with distribution=hash[some_id].  I have a query on this only one table but with multiple WHERE conditions, including one on 'some_id'. Performance are poor, so i'm trying to find a solution which allow me to avoid my query to do a full scan of all rowgroups. First i'm trying to find the best way to monitor impact of my query in regard of table definition (e.g. rowgroups skipping)

Comment: Single-distribution queries are a challenge.  If it's a common scenario your distribution choice may not be optimal.  Or you may need to implement partitioning (your table is big enough) and/or CCI ordering and/or secondary indexes.  Or perhaps a materialized view.

Comment: Even data loading is a challenge with this kind of volume. But yes i'm thinking about partitions/index/... but first i want to have clear idea about how each solution internally worked (this is why i'm looking for a solution to monitor it ... execution plan is ok but it's not DBCC TRACEON).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214850/discussion-between-david-browne-microsoft-and-al3xisb).